# Why does this Google Sheets IF statement return "#Value" instead of "0"

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a pretty simple IF statement in my google sheet:

```
=IF(SEARCH("PM",K2)>0,1,0)
```

Basically, I'm asking if cell K2 has "PM" in it.  K2 is a time in the format of "H:MM:SS AM/PM".  When this returns true, it gives me a value of "1", otherwise it gives me "#VALUE" with an error of

> In SEARCH evaluation, cannot find 'PM' within '8:02:48 AM'.

Why the heck won't this return as "0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how [`SEARCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en-GB) works. It returns `#VALUE!` if the string is not found. If you want a 0, I suggest

```
=IFERROR(N(SEARCH("AM",K2)>0),0)
```

The `N` is for consistent data typing. Or, even shorter:

```
=IFERROR(1^SEARCH("PM",K2),0)
=IFERROR(SEARCH("PM",K2)^0,0)
```